Probability terminology common usage
I'm working through a probability class and am having some trouble nailing down exactly what the terminology used means, since the definitions of these terms online seem to be different than what's used in the book (or I'm just misunderstanding something else, in which case clarifying that would be just as helpful!). Specifically, the problematic terms for me are

Do people typically refer to the density of a random variable as the same thing as its PDF? (ex. problem #16)
Does saying two random variables X and Y are jointly discrete mean their joint distribution function isn't continuous? (I'm guessing this is the case, but just wondering because it seems odd & I'm wondering if I'm missing something.) (ex. #17)
If I was finding the PMF of a random vector, wouldn't that be the same as finding its distribution function? I'm confused here because the last two sentences of #17 seem to be asking the same thing, just with the second also throwing in jointly discrete. I thought PMF was just a type of distribution function – are these two sentences in the problem not the same?
Is distribution function (with no qualifier) generally understood to mean "cumulative distribution function" and it's a good idea to assume this?


(Please note: This isn't homework, and I'm not asking for you to solve these for me anyways; I'm just including them to give context to how the terms are being used.)
I realize this is technically multiple questions, but they're all related and small, so it seemed sensible to group them into one. I'd really appreciate and clarifications you're able to provide here in terms of just understanding exactly what is being asked in the problems. Thanks so much in advance!

(1) Yes, people treat density and PDF as the same in probability theory; (2) Discrete (and so "jointly discrete") means all the probability is on a finite or countable set (you can have distributions which are neither fully continuous nor fully discrete); (3 & 4) I would regard a "distribution function" as being a CDF (cumulative distribution function) though knowing a PMF for a discrete distribution (or a PDF for an absolutely continuous distribution) may fix what the CDF is, and so some people are looser in their language.

Also for (1): “density” can also mean a measure that isn't given by a (probability density) function—for example, a random variable that is 50% likely to be uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ and 50% likely to equal $\frac12$ exactly.
